# React Hook form clear errors on click

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I'm implementing validation into my application, currently everything is working, the user gets an error message on wrong input and so on. The only thing I have left to do is to implement a field reset, if the user's input corresponds to the requirements of the validator.

I'm using React-Hook-Form and React yup. If I now click out of a field and it is empty, an error gets shown, if I click in again and type something then the error goes away. BUT if I click out into another field the error message stays there, even though the input is correct. Now this obviously isn't how I want it to work.

Here are my yup and react hook form variables

```
    const providerSchema = yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    parent: yup.string().required().min(3),
    website: yup.string().required().matches(/^(https:|http:|www\\.)\\S*/gm),
    street: yup.string().required().min(3),
    city: yup.string().required().min(2),
    zipCode: yup.number().required().min(4),
    country: yup.number().required()
});
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}, clearErrors } = useForm({ mode: "onTouched", reValidateMode: "onChange" , resolver: yupResolver(providerSchema)});
```

And here are two of multiple fields I'm using in the form:

```
<div>
     <div className="mb-3">
      <label className={`${errors.street ? "text-red-700" : "text-black-400"}`}>Street</label>
       <input {...register("street")} id="street" className={`${
         errors.street ? "text-red-600 border-red-400" 
         : "text-black-200 border-black-400"}`} type="text" placeholder="Street" ref= 
         {streetRef} onChange={() => clearErrors()}/>
           {errors.street && (
            <p className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">
               Street is required.
            </p>
           )}
      </div>
  </div>


<div className="mb-3">
 <label className={`${errors.city ? "text-red-700" : "text-black-400"}`}>City</label>
  <input {...register("city")} id="city" className={`${
    errors.city ? "text-red-600 border-red-400"
    : "text-black-200 border-black-400"}`} type="text" placeholder="City" ref={cityRef} 
    onChange={() => clearErrors()}/>
     {errors.city && (
       <p className="text-red-500 text-sm mt-2">
           City is required.
       </p>
      )}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be issue with schema or with setup w schema-

from rhf examples:

```
const schema = yup.object({
  firstName: yup.string().required(),
  age: yup.number().positive().integer().required(),
}).required();
```

Try removing mode: "onTouched"